# Are "loose" circles typical in optimal circle packings?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, packing-problem

There has been much work done on finding optimal packings of $k$ congruent circular discs in a larger circle; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) or [here](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/) for a tabulation of many results.

Scrolling through the results, one sees that for small values of $k$, the circles are usually very tightly constrained, but for higher $k$ we often find that some of the circles in an optimal packing are untethered to any of their neighbors and can freely move around. The latter of the two links in the previous paragraph clearly lists the number of loose circles in each packing, and it appears that [this configuration](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci91.html) with $91$ circles is the largest $k$ for which the best packing has no loose circles:

[image]

Everything else seems to exhibit this behavior for higher $k$ up through $2600$ (at least, of the best-known arrangements).

**What can be proven about this behavior?** In particular, I am curious which of the following things have been shown about the set of positive integers $k$ such that the optimal packing of $k$ circles in a circle has loose discs:

- The set is infinite.
- The set has positive natural density.
- The set has density $1$.
- The set is cofinite.
- The set contains all integers greater than $N$ for some explicitly known $N$.

I expect that all of the above conditions are *true*, and probably with $N=91$, but given how hard individual cases are to prove optimality for I could imagine that it is very difficult to show later items on this list. What is known in the literature about such results?

I have chosen the circle as a natural packing target for which much work appears to have been done already, but I would also be interested in analogous results for circle packing in a square (or general results about circle packing in any sufficiently non-pathological shape, for which I would expect similar kinds of statements to hold).

Comment: Given how hard it is to prove anything at all about the cardinality of optimal packings (for example the vast majority of data in those links seems to be computational and experimental and to provide only upper bounds to optimal cardinality), can you add to your question some explanation of why one would expect to be able to prove anything at all regarding still finer properties of optimal packing than mere cardinality, e.g. existence of loose circles?

Comment: @LeeMosher: One can compute with proof the limiting density of circle packings for large $k$ (namely $\pi/\sqrt{12}$), despite exact values being extremely difficult to show. So it is not in general true that global properties of these packings are inaccessible to rigorous proof. As a qualitative sketch, perhaps one could show non-loose packings must meet certain geometric conditions if they are to be maximal, which restricts the possibilities enough to rule out such configurations appearing too often. (As I stated, though, I would be quite surprised to find later items in that list proven.)

Comment: Hilbert's 18th problem, "What is the densest sphere packing?", has been studied extensively.

Comment: @FreeMind: I am aware of the work done on dense sphere packings in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and Hales' proof of the Kepler conjecture; I do not see their relevance to this question. Is there some connection you see between Hilbert's 18th problem and this post, beyond their general relation to arrangements of disjoint spheres?